# ¿Es correcta la expresión "descartado que" para indicar que algo es trivial?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones, significado

En una clase grabada en Youtube (no adjunto el enlace porque dura varias horas y no recuerdo en qué momento se usa) he escuchado:

> **descartado que** se puede hacer tal cosa

Significando que es trivial el que se pueda hacer esa cosa. Esto me pareció contradictorio con el significado que conocía del verbo [*descartar*](https://dle.rae.es/descartar).

Las primeras dos acepciones del diccionario de la RAE son:

> 1. tr. Excluir o eliminar a alguien o algo.
> 2. tr. Rechazar, no admitir algo

Si la frase que hubieran usado fuese:

> Descartado que puedo hacer A en esta situación. Hacemos B.

Entendería que del abanico de opciones posibles se descarta A (por ser trivial, no incorrecta) y se hace B. Pero la he escuchado en contextos como

> Descartado que se puede hacer A. Entonces, hacemos A.

¿Es una expresión armada? ¿Qué significa y cómo se usa?

Comment: Yo preferiría "descarta**n**do que", aunque no lo veo mal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La voz *descartado* no tiene, como afirmas, ningún significado como el que dices que se le da en el vídeo. Lo he comprobado tanto en el DLE como el *Diccionario de Americanismos*.

Sin embargo, hay una voz parecida que sí que tiene ese significado:

> **[descontado](https://dle.rae.es/descontado)**
>
> Del part. de *descontar*.
>
> **dar** alguien algo **por descontado**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Contar con ello como seguro e indiscutible.
>
> **por descontado**
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Por supuesto, sin duda alguna.

Es probable que el autor del vídeo haya confundido la expresión y en realidad haya querido decir "por descontado que se puede hacer tal cosa".

Comment: "Descontando que" me suena muy bien pero "descartando que" tampoco me suena mal. Pues **descartando o excluyendo la posibilidad de A** das **por descontado** esa misma posibilidad. Con "descontado" usas una **expresión idiomática**. Con "descartando" usas el verbo  'descartar' de manera normal.